# Back navigation from WebBrowser form pops stack too many times - Android CodenameOne

Tags: android, codenameone

Looking for advice here.

I have a simple empty Form in my UIBuilder app that puts a web browser component in the Center of its BorderLayout in its "beforeVideoScreen" method.  it loads an external page (embedded Youtube link) set in code.

It will help my explanation for you to understand my forms hierarchy (all UI Builder based):

Main --> Categories --> Topics --> Details --> Video Viewer

On Samsung Galaxy Android devices (I have an SG3 running 4.4 and and SG6 running  5.1), when I am on the "Video Viewer" form and press the back button on the device, i see a strange visual effect - like back-navigating twice to the same screen.  I arrive at the correct form (the "Details" form), but if I navigate back from "Details" all the steps to Main, it skips the Categories Form.

Now it gets interesting:  If I go back and forth between "Video Viewer" and "Details" repeatedly, I eventually have NO back stack from the details form.  (if I do the "Video Viewer" back to "Details" cycle this way twice, then 2 forms are missing, 3 times and 3 forms are missing etc) it just exits the app.  Makes me think that it's double-dipping on the back-stack.

On the simulator and physical iOS device it does not exhibit this behaviour.   if I remove the Web Browser component and instead place a static image, it doesn't exhibit this behaviour so it's not the UIBuilder/forms structure itself etc.  It seems isolated to the WebBrowser component being on the screen when hitting the back key on the device.

So my question:  I can't think of a way to troubleshoot this.  Can anyone recommend either a way to troubleshoot this behaviour (native Android browser....)  or any known issues/workarounds for it?

Comment: I'm looking into this, there is support for grabbing the back button for some use cases but it shouldn't be implicit.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a potential fix to address this issue, this is under review so I'm not sure if it's the "right thing":
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/e5fb68fa881d680746a34134a368da91b71bc71b

Comment: Shai, how can I test this with my code? Should I pull the git and compile it?  I did find a workaround for now: I change the back command on the video screen to set the page to a blank HTML page to stop the video playing, then I replace the Browser with a label before I call the "back()" command. so far it works and doesn't look too bad, but a fix would be ideal.

Comment: We now release updates every Friday so if  this isn't fixed by Sunday the problem is still there http://www.codenameone.com/blog/weekly-release-developer-guide-javascript-promotion-end.html